# Select the newly added dynamic row in UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am working with a MasterDetail View using SplitViewController  in iPad, My Master View has a tableView where I add rows dynamically. So the newly added row sits at zero postion. So what I want to achieve is that, I want to select the newly added row as soon as it is added to the Master table. Later when the user adds a new row, that row should be selected and the previously added row should be deselected.

For this I have written the code below

```
- (void)selectNewlyAddedRow
{
            NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [m_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:TRUE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [self tableView:m_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
}
```

This code works if I write it in function ViewDidAppear, but if I write it in cellForRowAtIndexPath it doesnt work..

Please provide me correct understanding where I am going wrong.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: if code is working fine why bothering write same code in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method. That Method is only for creating cells and assigning text to labels or images.

Comment: ViewDidAppear is right place buddy

Comment: @RahulVyas, I tried it in cellForRowAtIndexPath and also in ViewDidAppear, but it doesnt work

Comment: only write this code in ViewDidAppear. Do not write this code in cellForRow method

Comment: but when I add a new row, ViewDidAppear is not called. So whats the point in writing there.

Comment: ok write the code just below where you are adding a new row

Comment: Hi @RahulVyas, It works, but when I scroll and the row goes out of the  screen then that row is no more in selected state.How to solve this.

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath assume you have added a new Row so you can take a Bool like newRowAdded and make it TRUE. After this in cellForRow Method if(newRowAdded && indexPath.row == 0) {
 [cell setSelected]; //Whatever method we have for display cell as selected. I hope you understand
}

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear wont get call when you add new row so you just register for table reloaded notification and in method for that notification call select first row I hope it will help you....

```
   - (void)selectFirstRow{

        if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] > 0 && [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 0) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
            [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey how to register for table reloaded notification.

Comment: Implement this delegate - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{ [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
            [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"Table Reloaded" object:nil];}  In your view controller add this line in viewdidload    -(void)viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReloaded:) name:@"Table Reloaded" object:nil];}

Comment: So I should write it inside this

Comment: -(void) tableReloaded:(NSNotification*)notification{ [self selectFirstRow]];}

Comment: hi , this is not working, this function is not called when I add the new row.

Comment: which function? delegate or notification receiver?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29719/discussion-between-ranjit-and-jailani-habeeb)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate -

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView )tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath{ 
          [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
          [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"Table Reloaded" object:nil];
    }
```

In your view controller add this line in viewdidload

```
   -(void)viewDidLoad{ 
          [super viewDidLoad];
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReloaded:) name:@"Table Reloaded" object:nil];
   }


  -(void) tableReloaded:(NSNotification*)notification{ 
        [self selectFirstRow];
  }
```